# How do I boot Ubuntu Cloud images in KVM?

Tags: cloud, kvm-virtualization, cloud-init

I'm trying to get an Ubuntu Cloud image running on my local KVM installation.

I am downloading the qcow2 image from here:

- http://cloud-images.ubuntu.com/releases/precise/beta-2/

And using the instructions from here:

- https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UEC/Images#DownloadUECImages

I cannot find a way to get the password for the instance. The instructions say that GRUB creates the password on first boot and that it is written to the console. What I haven't found is a way to read what is sent to the console. It scrolls too fast to view in the VNC console.

It seems like there should be a way to send console output to a file, but if there is such a method I cannot find it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're following the documentation for "Local Hypervisor Natty onward", then you should be able to log in with `ubuntu` and `passw0rd`.

cloud-init in 12.04 images has a more straight forward way of providing customization data to images than the OVF data source that is described there.

For documentation on setting the password for 12.04 cloud images see:

- https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UEC/Images#line-107

The cloud-init project is hosted on launchpad at:

- https://launchpad.net/cloud-init

For more information on the cloud init project see the documentation at

- http://cloudinit.readthedocs.org/en/latest/

Answer (score 0):

Those instructions in the OP dont work anymore with the new images that dont contain a floppy disk file or kernel files, see here: [What are the different versions available as Ubuntu cloud-images?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1375589/what-are-the-different-versions-available-as-ubuntu-cloud-images). Also the password is created randomly on each start by cloud-init.

Comment: This is not an answer, maybe it was meant to be a comment on the answer? If this were an answer, it would tell us how to get the password in 2021.

Comment: @Jeremy, actually it is. Did you even look at the link I provided? It is about a 1000 word answer, not only to how to set the password, but how to get cloud images running on many formats in Linux, KVM, Virt-manager, Vbox. I suppose you wanted me to copy that all over here, just for people who couldnt take the time to click a link before downvoting and commenting negatively before reading? Btw, you're welcome in advance. Yes, it's super frustrating, but don't take that out on the people who are trying to help.

Comment: And obviously if the link in my answer goes down, so will this question because they are both on AskUbuntu. As well as the main link in the accepted answer from a decade ago is now incorrect.

Comment: this isn't my idea, it is the policy of stack exchange that the answers to the question should be in the answer, and not in a link.